# Do I need to add zustand store to useEffect dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, zustand

I have a `zustand` store, like this

```js
import create from 'zustand';

export const useNotificationStore = create((set) => ({
  notifications: [],
  addMessage: (payload) =>
    set((state) => ({
      notifications: [
        ...state.notifications,
        { ...payload },
      ],
    }))
}));
```

When using this store in React component, do I need to add this store to dependency list? For example

```js
function Notify() {
  const notify = useNotificationStore();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // do something async
    notify.addMessage({ ... })
  }, [dependency1]) // do I need to add notify here?

  return <div />
}
```

For `redux`, there was no need to add `dispatch` to dependency list. Is it true for `zustand`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes – there's nothing stopping you from doing `set({addMessage: ...})`, and so `notify.addMessage` would change.

Practically: probably not.

Answer (score -1):

> For redux, there was no need to add dispatch to dependency list

Well, even though it is technically not needed to add `dispatch` to dependency lists in Redux, it is still a much better practice to include it anyway rather than ignoring/suppressing ESLint's warnings (or not using ESLint at all). So I'd suggest to always follow what the ESLint rule says. If it ends up never changing, then it doesn't hurt.